# S3: Grant access to xml list by access key + javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a javascript code that gets the xml list `http://BUCKETNAME.s3.REGION.amazonaws.com/` of s3 bucket and uses it as a playlist:

```
    AWS.config=
    { "accessKeyId": "ACCESS KEY",
    "secretAccessKey": "SECRET KEY",
    "region": "REGION" };
    // Create S3 service object
    s3 = new AWS.S3();

    var params = {
    Bucket: 'BUCKET NAME', /* required */
    Delimiter: '',
    EncodingType: 'url',
    Marker: '',
    MaxKeys: 0,
    Prefix: '',
    RequestPayer: 'requester'
    };


    s3.listObjects(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
    else
    {
        console.log('the list is approved '); // successful response
     // Here is the function that convert the file list in the xml to an array
        var b = document.documentElement;
    b.setAttribute('data-useragent', navigator.userAgent);
    b.setAttribute('data-platform', navigator.platform);
    var radioName;
    var radioTitle;
    var tracklength= 0;
    // setupPlayer function
    function setupPlayer(href,name){
        radioName= href;
        radioTitle= name;

     $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://BUCKETNAME.s3.REGION.amazonaws.com/?prefix=radio/"+radioName+"/",
            dataType: "xml",
            success: function(xml){
                //tracklength=0;
                tracks =[];
                $(xml).find('Contents').each(function(){
                    tracklength=tracklength+1;
                    tracks.push({
                        "track": tracklength,
                        "file" : $(this).find('Key').text()
                    });
                });
                radio(tracks);

            },
            error: function() {
                alert("An error occurred while processing XML file.");
            }
        });
    }
    }
```

As you can see, in this code I am taking the XML file and add a radio name (which is the folder name) , after that the ajax will save all the file names in this folder to an array `tracks`.

This code works perfectly if there is a list grantee permission for Everyone. So there is no need for aws config here. I can run the code inside `else` statement in `listObjects` function and it will give me the same response.

What I do want is to give the grant access to this key only, to make this function not work without the access key and secret key.

So no one can access the xml list except those who have the access and secret keys.

Is that possible ?

*(This is not the full code, but you got the Idea, accessing the XML file of the bucket and getting the keys an saving them to an array).*

Comment: Are you looking to access the S3 Bucket using access/secret key only. If so then its possible. Make you bucket private and then write a policy to access this bucket and associate this policy against the user whose access/secret key you want to use.

Comment: @Rajesh , I already did that and I wrote this code but it doesn't work,, I don't know how

Answer (score 0):

You should use s3.getObject (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#getObject-property) to get your xml files instead of $.ajax call.

Comment: can I list object in each folder in the bucket? , because I have folders in the bucket, I need to list the keys in each folder..

Comment: s3.listObjects can list all objects in a bucket (folder is just an object for S3)